# Best way to mock java web service

Tags: java, web-services, mocking

I have to mock quite complicated java web service and I'm searching for the right solution. One way to do it would be to use Soap UI, but I need something that would be able to modify server state ie. one request would affect future requests.

In this particular case it could be done quickly by saving serialized objects to disk and sometimes spawning asynchronous responses to the originating client webservice.

Those two requirements are preventing me from using SoapUI - the groovy logic would become quite complicated and probably hard to mantain.

My questions:

1) Are there any other SoapUI advantages in this context (eg. easy migration to new version of wsdl) over custom java mock implementation?

2) What would be most appropriate way to generate the webservice from wsdl and still be able too hook up with some custom functionality, ie. by attaching some hooks that would be editable in seperate files (to facilitate further ws code regeneration from updated wsdl)?

Comment: I should also note, that the mock is not only for testing purposes and it should leave the client part as-is, ie. there has to be regular http communication, just the endpoint changes. So I guess mocking framework won't do in this case.

Comment: If you're talking integration testing then I'd try to mirror your production environment as closely as possible and would use the real web-service against a UAT/QA database. If the web-service isn't under your control then look at creating 'test' data that you use during your tests. IMHO creating a 'mock'/stub of the web-service gives you a false sense of security because your 'mock'/stub is based on your assumptions of how the web-service will behave. This is ok in unit tests but for a full integration test you've gotta use the real thing to be sure it works.

Comment: Not really integration testing, rather think about using it for training purposes. Since webservices that the frontend uses are really hard to mirror (lots of sensitive data) it's easier to create some lightweight mock, but intelligent enough to maintain the state and hence provide possibility of logical training scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple mocks I use soapUI, while for more complicated when state must change between request I use simple web service emulator written in Python. Such emulator use reply templates created from real web service or responses I created in soapUI. This way I can control all logic.

Emulator for my last project has 300+ lines of Python code, but for previous, much simplier, it was ~150 lines of Python code.

Comment: That sounds cool and all but is it available?

Comment: soapUI is free (there is also paid more advaced edition). Python scripts I use for emulator are vary service specified: they use HTTP server and fills replies based on template and some database value.

Answer (score 5):

You should look at [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/), which allows to build mocks programatically. It is possible to specify very complex behaviors for your mocks.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you're using some sort of generated stub in your client?  You should mock stub with one of the mocking APIs (JMock or EasyMock) and inject the mock into the class-under-test.

On the server-side test that class that handles the call, injecting mocks of any objects it might use to do its job.

As an aside you should strive to keep all the calls in a unit test local (in-process).  It makes it easy to control return values from any objects the class-under-test depends on and when the test suite grows will help prevent the unit tests becoming a bottle neck in your build process.

With regards to generating a Java class(es) from WSDL Apache Axis has something called WSDL2Java, which generates the client stubs I mentioned earlier.  This sort of utility is common in the web service frameworks but may have been replaced now since EJB3 web services introduced `javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory` exists.

There's a tutorial on EJB3 web services and clients here (http://www.theregister.co.uk/2007/01/23/ejb_web_services/).